# LINQ to XML: Project to a List<string>

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Using LINQ to XML, how can I project the following XML data into a `List<string>` with the values "Test1", "Test2" and "Test3".

```
<objectlist>
    <object code="Test1" />
    <object code="Test2" />
    <object code="Test3" />
</objectlist>
```

I have the XML available in a string:

```
XDocument xlist = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? (It's very simple, but it's important to learn to try things yourself first, and report them when you ask a question.)

Comment: What have you tried? This is trivial and there are A LOT questions about this here in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
List<string> codes = xDoc.Descendants("object")
                        .Select(o => o.Attribute("code").Value)
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from node in xlist.Root.Elements("object")
            select node.Attribute("code").Value

var result = query.ToList();
```

Or, with extension method syntax:

```
var query = xlist.Root.Elements("object")
               .Select(node => node.Attribute("code").Value)
               .ToList()
```

Comment: Why use a query expression here? It just adds noise compared with the extension method calls.

Comment: It does in complicated queries - but here it's *increasing* noise, particularly because you then want to call `ToList()` afterwards. I usually find that if you're *just* doing a `Select` or a `Where`, query expressions are noisier than extension method syntax.

Comment: I MUCH prefer chaining extension methods but thanks for the answer anyway :)

Comment: Davenewza, how can you much prefer something when you didn't know how to chain it to begin with..I am confused..?

Comment: I added the extension method variant for comparison, but I'm still favouring the query expression. I think it's the lambda's that turn me off... Also, I *like* the fact that the query definition is seperated from query evaluation (`ToList()`). Everyone's entitled to his own opinion though :-)

Comment: @DJ KRAZE:  I've been using LINQ everyday for years.  I have never used LINQ to XML before so I'm completely unfamiliar with the classes.  I did begin by looking in MSDN but realised that I would get a better/quicker answer here. I'm pressured to finish a project and I just need to quickly parse a bit of XML.

Comment: Understandable.. my apologies